# Who will enter into the final in case of rain in first qualifier?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, indian-premier-league, interruption

What happens if it rains in the first qualifier in IPL 2014 match between KKR and KXIP?

Who will enter into the final? On what basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the match abandoned due to rain, then the match will be postponed to May 28(reserve day for first qualifier match).

If the match still abandoned on the reserve day, then the team([KXI Punjab](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2014/engine/series/695871.html?view=pointstable)) which finished in the higher position in the points table  will be deemed the winner of the match.

**Ref**: [IPL Playing Conditions 21.10](http://www.iplt20.com/about/2014/match-playing-conditions/26/law-21-the-result)